# Where to put “per fax/mail in advance” in scrlttr2?

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

If you send something with a formal/legaö letter, you may provide a copy via mail or fax or so before. If so, you usually change that copy to include something like this:

> per fax followed by letter
> per mail followed by letter

or:

> per fax in advance
> per mail in advance

If I style my letter with scrlttr2, where do I put that?

The receiver address field is bad to abuse and I only found the `specialmail` KOMA variable. However, this includes it at the top right of the address field and underlines it.
I guess this is supposed to be used for something else.
So **could you please also explain to me, what I should use `specialmail` for?**

#### What I expect

As far as I have seen in most letters these words are printed *after* or – **more often** (and I would prefer that) – one or two lines *before* the receiver's address.
The text is usually written `--` surrounded by two or three hypens `--`.

So in the end, it may look like this:

> -- per mail in advance --
>
> Don Joe
> c/o Some Company Org
> Goodstreet 3
> 0283 City
> Germany
>
> **Subject:** Demonstration for StackExchange
>
> Dear Mr. Joe,
> […]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not use KOMA variable `location` yet, you can set this variable to

```latex
\setkomavar{location}{-{}- per mail in advance -{}-}
```

Then you can adjust the position of the location field to your needs, eg:

```latex
\setplength[-]{lochpos}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\setplength{locvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
\setplength{locwidth}{\useplength{toaddrwidth}}
\setplength[2]{locheight}{\baselineskip}
\addtoplength[-2]{locvpos}{\baselineskip}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

%% to show the position of fields address and location:
%\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
%\showfields{address,location}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\setkomavar{fromname}{rugk}
\setkomavar{location}{-{}- per mail in advance -{}-}

% change the position of the location field
\setplength[-]{lochpos}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\setplength{locvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
\setplength{locwidth}{\useplength{toaddrwidth}}
\setplength[2]{locheight}{\baselineskip}
\addtoplength[-2]{locvpos}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Don Joe\\c/o Some Company Org\\Goodstreet 3\\0283 City\\Germany}
\opening{Dear Mr. Joe,}
\blindtext
\closing{Best regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]